# iCloud Core Data Not available after running in Xcode 6 / ios 8 SDK

Tags: core-data, icloud

I have an app that uses Core Data with iCloud sync. It works great in iOS 7.

I'm having some trouble since running it in XCode 6 though, even on an iOS 7 device. Here's my test:

- on iOS 7 device: Download current live app from app store
- Sync data from iCloud
- Build and run new version of app
- Persistent Stores change, original data no longer available

Here's screen shots of my provisioning profile and xcode setup:

[image]

I've also tried the following entitlements:

1. Just `com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers`
2. `com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers` this is what I had before. When I run the test with this in place the data is there first time but not on second run. There's no events about the store changing, but it says `Using local storage: 1` on first and second run
3. Both of the above. Get the same results as #2

Comment: any updates/solution received from Apple Support? I have the same problem

Comment: Apple have said that running the ad hoc build with a new model will not work, but a signed/app store version will work. Terrifying! Will report back either way.

Comment: really? how can we test it? The problem seems still exists for my test flight beta version. Please keep me posted what you see. thx.

Comment: if i were you I would raise your own ticket with apple, you can't mess around with this stuff and no one can have the knowledge they do. you get 2 tickets with your app store membership. you will probably have an answer  from them before you do form me

Answer (score 3):

It looks like based on the screenshot of the entitlements that you have both the old (ubiquity container) and new (iCloud container) related entitlements. I found, and have seen reported, issues when both old and new entitlements are present.

For my app I kept only the old entitlements and deleted the two new ones that XCode 6 will attempt to add to fix issues that it believes are present with iCloud. The two keys I removed were:

- com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers
- com.apple.developer.icloud-services

I kept only the original key (com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers) and did not change it's value. With that the app still works in iOS 7 when built using XCode 6 GM and can access all of the data as before. In iOS 8 it will also work however it seems to require the user to have updated their account to iCloud Drive.

Comment: Thanks for this Iain. Unfortunately it doesn't work :( I've updated the question

Comment: If you're seeing "Using local storage: 1" then that is promising. That means it is at least connecting to iCloud. Is it ever changing to "Using local storage: 0" ? Is this on a device or the simulator?

Comment: It's on the device. It shows Using local storage: 1 on both runs, but the data isn't available on the second run.

Comment: If it's never changing to "Using local storage: 0" then that means it is stuck on only the temporary store. If you run the app on your device via Xcode does it show any iCloud activity? Is the initial amount of data to synchronise very large?

Comment: Hi @Iain thanks for your time and expertise. I've raised this with Apple Developer Technical Support as after your help and a few others I'm not convinced that it's me making a mistake any more. Thanks again. I'll post the answer when I get it.